# Timeline of file modification (grouped by day)

Tags: python, pandas, markdown, pandas-groupby

The code below is scanning all markdown files in the folder and collecting the name of file and modification date in 2 separated list. After that I combine both list as Panada object. My idea for that was that in Pandas I can group data based on day, but unfortunately I got stuck in this place. I have no idea what to do with panda object to archive this:

**This is what the scrip below generate:**

```
               modification date        file
datetime    
2020-07-26 13:33:37 2020-07-26 13:33:37 File1
2020-07-26 10:15:50 2020-08-03 10:15:50 File2
2020-07-25 22:30:01 2020-08-20 22:30:01 File3
2020-07-25 10:01:02 2020-07-30 10:01:02 File4
2020-07-25 10:34:53 2020-08-19 10:34:53 File5
```

**This is what I like to get**

(Files from same day are under same "heading" and list of files with time is inserted for each row. All (date and time) is sorted from lates to last.

```
## 26.7 (Sunday)

13:33 | File1
10:15 | File2

## 25.7 (Saturday)

22:30 | File3
10:34 | File5
10:01 | File4
```

**The current code (until panda object)**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
from pathlib import Path 
from dateutil import parser

File_vault = "any folder path"
File_ext = "*.md"

List_names = []
List_dates = []

# RECURSIVE UNSORTED LOOP OF MARKDOWN FILES
for file in Path(File_vault).rglob(File_ext):
    
    file_stamp = os.path.getctime(file)
    
    # FILL LISTS WITH DATA
    List_names.append((file.name).replace(File_ext,""))
    List_dates.append(parser.parse(time.ctime(file_stamp)))

# CONVERT TO PANDA OBJECT
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['datetime'] = List_dates
df.index = df['datetime'] 
df['file'] = List_names
df.head()
```

Anybody who can help?

Answer (score 0):

You would need the following changes in your code.
Rather than creating two list with grouping done here I have created a nested list with three columns Date,time and filename.

```
#Date data
ddate = parser.parse(time.ctime(file_stamp))
#Nested list of date,time and filename
List_names.append([ddate.date(),ddate.time(),(file.name).replace(File_ext,"")])
```

Created the pandas Dataframe based using the list, provided column names and used pandas groupby method to get the output.

```
#DF Creation
df = pd.DataFrame(List_names)
df.columns = ['date','time', 'file']
df_grouped = df.groupby('date')
#looping over the grouped data and printing output
for group, gdf in df_grouped:
    print('Day:', group, '\n')
    print( gdf.iloc[:, 1:], '\n')
```

Below you can find the entire code and the output snapshot.

Note: change the File_vault,File_ext variable as required

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
from pathlib import Path 
from dateutil import parser
import os
import time


File_vault = ""
File_ext = ""

List_names = []

# RECURSIVE UNSORTED LOOP OF MARKDOWN FILES
for file in Path(File_vault).rglob(File_ext):
    
    file_stamp = os.path.getctime(file)
    ddate = parser.parse(time.ctime(file_stamp))
    # FILL LISTS WITH DATA
    List_names.append([ddate.date(),ddate.time(),(file.name).replace(File_ext,"")])

# CONVERT TO PANDA OBJECT

df = pd.DataFrame(List_names)
df.columns = ['date','time', 'file']
df_grouped = df.groupby('date')
for group, gdf in df_grouped:
    print('Day:', group, '\n')
    print( gdf.iloc[:, 1:], '\n')
```

OUTPUT

```
Day: 2020-07-31 

       time          file
1  15:34:54  sample_1.png
2  15:34:56  sample_2.png
3  15:34:58  sample_3.png
4  15:35:00  sample_4.png 

Day: 2020-08-30 

       time          file
0  14:22:52    New folder
5  14:22:58  sample_1.png
```

You can change the column names if required!

Comment: That was answer approaching speed of light! Yes, before I tried to put all in one list, but Pandas complain for some reason, then I switched to 2 columns.

Your answer is 99% what I need. I tried to sort the field in revers order (from latest to oldest) by adding ```df.sort_index``` but for some reason Pandas still produce same order like before.

Comment: When trying your code in my folder the ordering by time is completely random and ordering by day is in reverse order.  I have tried various sorting methods, but as always I'm failing in Pandas... if you have any pointer for me how to do that, I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

The desired sorting was solved by adding:

```
df.sort_values(by=['date','time'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
df_grouped = df.groupby('date', sort=False)
```

**FUNCTIONAL CODE:**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
from pathlib import Path 
from dateutil import parser
import os
import time

File_vault = "" #folder path
File_ext = ""   #file extension
List_names = []

# RECURSIVE UNSORTED LOOP OF MARKDOWN FILES
for file in Path(File_vault).rglob(File_ext):
    
    file_stamp = os.path.getctime(file)
    ddate = parser.parse(time.ctime(file_stamp))
    # FILL LISTS WITH DATA
    List_names.append([ddate.date(),ddate.time(),(file.name).replace(File_ext,"")])

# CONVERT TO PANDA OBJECT
df = pd.DataFrame(List_names)
df.columns = ['date','time', 'file']

# DATE SORTING
df.sort_values(by=['date','time'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
df_grouped = df.groupby('date', sort=False)

for group, gdf in df_grouped:
    print('Day:', group, '\n')
    print( gdf.iloc[:, 1:], '\n')
```

*Thank you very much @Rikigami!*